# What group is $IISO(1)$?

Tags: geometry, group-theory, definition

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9910041.pdf), on page 10, the authors describe the group of motions of "galilean space" as $IISO(1)$. I can't find any definition of this group within the paper, or online.

It's used alongside $ISO(2)$ for the group of motions of $2d$ Euclidean space. They also use $ISO(1,1)$, which I think is defined on page 261 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1019.pdf).

What group does $IISO(1)$ refer to?

Comment: This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9612021 describes some "Galilean algebra" $iiso$.